# Error when I run compile in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a problem when I run compile 
I get this error

Errors during compilation:
        Ortho\Theme\Block\Html\Custommenu
                Incorrect dependency in class Ortho\Theme\Block\Html\Custommenu in /var/www/vhosts/domux.eu/dmx/app/code/Ortho/Theme/Block/Html/Custommenu.php
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 1

Can someone please tell me what code I have to remove or modify from this php file ?

```html
 public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,
  CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        \Ortho\Theme\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$nodeFactory,$treeFactory, $data);
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
       // $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        //$this->_menu = $this->getMenu();
$this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->treeFactory = $treeFactory;
    }
 
 /**
     * Get block cache life time
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        return parent::getCacheLifetime() ?: 3600;
    }
```

Thank you a lot.
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172655/magento-2-1-errors-during-compilation-incorrect-dependency-in-class.

You have here all explanation and how to solve it.